# Unauthenticated response status from firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

whenever i try to POST request to function https://europe-west3-[my-project].cloudfunctions.net/[my-function-name] i got a 401 response with body:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unauthenticated",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

the method itself consists of validation:

```
export const myFunctionName = regionFunctions.https.onCall(
    async (request, context) => {
        if (!userIsAuthenticated(context)) return {status: 401}

        if (!userIsAdmin(context)) return {status: 403}

        await syncCategories()

        return {status: 200}
    })

export const userIsAuthenticated = (context: CallableContext) => {
        return context.auth
    }
```

what I try to do, is to use **server key** from firebase project settings in request Authorization header.

Am I using wrong server key or what could be the issue?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For callable functions, you're typically not supposed to deal with headers at all.  The client SDK will handle all of that automatically for you, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

But if you do need to invoke a callable function directly using HTTPS, the Authorization header needs to be a Firebase Authentication user ID token as described in the [protocol documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).  It is not a server key.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Doug,

your answer helped me to fix this issue.

What I have done:
Logged in to my application, through browser console looked at user ID token, copied it to Authorization header and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use an API KEY from google cloud.
you must use this concept:
Request format: headers
The HTTP request to a callable trigger endpoint must be a POST with the following headers:
Optional: X-Firebase-AppCheck: 
The Firebase App Check token provided by the client app making the request. The backend automatically verifies this token and decodes it, injecting the appId in the handler's context. If the token cannot be verified, the request is rejected. (Available for SDK >=3.14.0)
If any other headers are included, the request is rejected, as described in the response documentation below.